# List all possible percentage splits for >3 inputs

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a list of all possible percentage splits between different number of stocks (a task required to build a proper investment opportunity set). I was able to create a macro tailored for 3 different inputs (the code is below).

Is it be possible to upgrade that macro so that it will automatically take into consideration the number of inputs (i.e. stock tickers) without the necessity to adjust the code every time? So that if input is 5 tickers instead of 3, it will create the list of all possible splits for 5 tickers?

Spreadsheet layout is simple: in row 1 I have a separate ticker in each column (3 tickers at the moment), and the split is provided below as:

```
     ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
row1 Ticker1 Ticker2 Ticker3
row2    0       0      100   
row3    0       1      99
etc.
```

Here's what I'm using for 3 inputs:

```
Sub PercentageSplits()

Dim Lastcol As Integer
Lastcol = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Sheet1.Cells(1, Lastcol + 1).Value = "Total"
Sheet1.Cells(1, Lastcol + 1).Font.Bold = True

Dim row As Integer: row = 2

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

For i = 0 To 100: For j = 0 To 100: For k = 0 To 100
    If i + j + k = 100 Then
        Sheet1.Cells(row, 1).Value = i
        Sheet1.Cells(row, 2).Value = j
        Sheet1.Cells(row, 3).Value = k
        Sheet1.Cells(row, Lastcol + 1).Value = i + j + k
        row = row + 1
    End If
Next: Next: Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a quick program together to calculate these and for a total of 100 split across 5 tickers, I got more than 4.5 million results (4,598,126 to be precise). That's way too many to fit on an Excel sheet.

To make sure that the output would fit on an Excel sheet, I halved the precision by calculating combinations of 5 tickers which added to 50 and then doubling the results. This gives 316,251 results.

If you need full precision then you could adapt the code to output the data in chunks of 1 million rows per worksheet

I don't often use recursion in VBA but it seemed the obvious way to answer this particular question. I'll explain some details below the code:

```
Option Explicit

' We'll store each result here
Dim splitList As Collection


Sub main()

Dim splitResult As Variant
Dim splitArray As Variant
Dim splitEntry As Variant
Dim outputArray() As Variant
Dim outputRow As Long
Dim outputCol As Long

' Initial set-up
Const TOTAL_TO_SPLIT As Integer = 50
Const NO_OF_TICKERS As Integer = 5
Set splitList = New Collection

' Generate the list
findSplit TOTAL_TO_SPLIT, 1, NO_OF_TICKERS, ""

MsgBox splitList.Count

' Output the list
ReDim outputArray(1 To splitList.Count, 1 To NO_OF_TICKERS)
outputRow = 1
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .UsedRange.Clear
    For Each splitResult In splitList
        outputCol = 1
        If Len(splitResult) > 0 Then
            splitArray = split(splitResult, ";")
            For Each splitEntry In splitArray
                outputArray(outputRow, outputCol) = splitEntry * 2
                outputCol = outputCol + 1
            Next splitEntry
        End If
        outputRow = outputRow + 1
    Next splitResult

    .Cells(2, 1).Resize(splitList.Count, NO_OF_TICKERS).Value = outputArray
End With

End Sub

' This sub is intended to be called recursively and will add an entry
' to splitList after each recursion concludes
Sub findSplit(amountToSplit As Integer, currentTicker As Integer, _ 
    totalTickers As Integer, resultSoFar As String)

Dim i As Integer

' Call DoEvents to prevent Excel from showing as "Not Responding"
DoEvents

' Check if this is the last ticker
If (currentTicker = totalTickers) Then
    splitList.Add resultSoFar & amountToSplit
Else
    For i = 0 To amountToSplit
        ' Otherwise, generate all the possible splits by recursion
        findSplit (amountToSplit - i), (currentTicker + 1), _
            totalTickers, (resultSoFar & i & ";")
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Notes:

- this is not going to run quickly. I suggest that you bring up the Locals window  (View > Locals window) in the Visual Basic editor before running the macro so you can periodically use Ctrl-Break to check on progress
- you could eliminate the collection and just write directly into the 2D array but I was trying to keep the recursive part of the code as simple as possible

It's probably easiest to understand the recursive sub (findSplit) by working backwards. If we are on the final ticker (so currentTicker = totalTickers) then we only have one possibility: the amount left over after all of the previous tickers needs to be allocated to the final ticker.

If we back up a level, if we are on the second-last ticker and the amount left over is 1 then we have two choices. Allocate 0 to the second-last ticker and pass 1 on to the last ticker OR allocate 1 to the second-last ticker and pass 0 on to the last ticker. Extending things to more tickers and/or greater amounts is just a repetition of these same two rules:

- if this is the last ticker, allocate whatever's left to this ticker
- if this is not the last ticker, try every possible allocation of whatever was left to this ticker and pass whatever is left over on to the next ticker

Each ticker adds the amount it was allocated to a string which is added to the collection by the last ticker. An entry of 14;6;0;13;17 shows that the ticker 1 was allocated 14, ticker 2 was allocated 6 and so on. As stated above, I reduced the number of results by calculating allocations against a total of 50 and then doubled the result. So the 14;6;0;13;17 combination would output as 28;12;0;26;34 (and you'll find it in row 228559 on the output worksheet).

The code in the main sub using Split and the For Each ... Next loops converts the strings stored in the collection into a 2D array of numbers that we can drop directly on to the worksheet

Comment: Hi barrowc. Sorry for not replying earlier, been away on a business trip. Didn't have a chance to try out your suggestion yet, although the logic behind it seems solid. Really wanted to thank you for spending your time for helping me out! Will reply back when i get the chance to run it in excel!

Comment: Hi barrowc, finally had time to try out your code - works like a charm. And extremely fast as well! Max up to 30 seconds depending on the number of tickers/percentage splits.  Updated it a bit to make the number of tickers as a variable, so thank you so much for that!